# How do I modify a textbox control so that pressing backspace deletes whole words instead of just one character at a time?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I would like to modify the default behavior of a regular WinForms C# textbox control so that pressing <kbd>backspace</kbd> deletes **whole words** instead of just a single character.

Ideally I would like to have this special behavior **only** when the caret position is in-front of a white-space character. For example; pressing <kbd>backspace</kbd> one time when the caret is at "hello world|" should still only remove one character resulting in "hello worl|" - but if the caret is at "hello world |" when I press <kbd>backspace</kbd>, then the result should be "hello |"

Comment: I think the convention is that Ctrl-backspace does this.

Comment: Ctrl+Bksp is not supported in WinForms textbox controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add `KeyEventHandler` for `KeyDown` event for your `TextBox`

```
this.textBox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyDown);
```

After that you can handle the event like this:

```
        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
            {
                int carretIndex = t.SelectionStart;
                if (carretIndex>0 && carretIndex == t.Text.Length && t.Text[carretIndex-1] == ' ')
                {
                    int lastWordIndex = t.Text.Substring(0, t.Text.Length - 1).LastIndexOf(' ');
                    if (lastWordIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        t.Text = t.Text.Remove(lastWordIndex + 1);
                        t.Select(t.Text.Length, 0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        t.Text = string.Empty;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @user805220 Well it's not perfect but it'll do!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the keypress/keydown events.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, I tested it out and it works fine:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        String[] chars = new String[1]{" "};

        if(e.KeyValue == 8)
        {
            var temp = (from string s in textBox1.Text.Split(chars, StringSplitOptions.None)
                             select s).ToArray();

            temp[temp.Length-1] = "";


            textBox1.Text = String.Join(" ",temp).ToString();
            SendKeys.Send("{END}");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a psuedo code, I hope you will find it helpful:

```
// check backspace is pressed
if keycode==keycode(backspace) then
    // testing cursor is just after space(113) character
    if string[string length] == keycode(space) then
    // loop through string in reverse order
    loop each character in reverse
        // start removing each character 
        remove the characters
    till find 2nd space

    end if
end if
```